# Mix JDO (DataNucleus) and JPA (Hibernate) objects in one transaction

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jdo, datanucleus

Is this going to be a problem?

I have a legacy system which uses javax.jdo API and XML mapping to handle writing/reading it's objects from the DB.

I also have some code that extends this system, this part is using JPA with Hibernate (via annotations, with Spring managed declarative transactions).

I would like to get them under the same umbrella, so I can manage the transactions better. I want to rewrite my code to use DataNucleus, but I'd like to stick with JPA (so I don't have to change the mappings, etc .. ).

So the question is: is it possible to mix JPA nad JDO in two parts of the project and span transactions over the mix? or do I have to choose only one approach?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataNucleus obviously would allow you to use JDO or JPA annotations (or both at the same time IIRC), and use persistence using either JDO or JPA (so JPA annotations with JDO PersistenceManager, and vice-versa). Likely if you have a PM for one part of the app and an EM for another part of the app then the transactions are separate.

Comment: In theory, if both are using JTA the transactions should not be separate.  Not sure about in practice though.

Answer (score 2):

This does not actually work in some situation, basically both hibernate and data nucleus uses its own generated proxies on persistent classes. So the proxy class generated in hibernate will not be recognized by data nucleus when you attempt to persist because it is a proxied class.

Comment: DataNucleus doesn't generate proxies as far as I see it, it uses bytecode weaving to inject the additional behavior to the original objects. Hibernate in contrast doesn't muck around with the bytecode so in order to fulfill its task it creates proxies on the fly. To your second point I did not say I want to persist Hibernate proxies with DataNucleus. I'd like to switch to DataNucleus implementation and keep the JDO and JPA annotations and API in place. Sorry for not being clear on that.